# JSON data in a list duplicating with Grails <g:each> incorporation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, grails

I am displaying a dynamic list of concerts, from a JSON source, on a page. These are also being added to my database from this source, but are not being displayed from my database on this page, for various reasons.

I want to include a link to the show page for each database concert in the list of concerts being displayed via JSON.

This acquires my JSON concerts:

```
  function fetch(){      
if($scope.search == "" || $scope.search == null){
  $.getJSON("http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search.json?&api_version=2.0&app_id=FYP&location=Dublin,Ireland", function(result) 
  {
    $scope.$apply(function()
    {
      $scope.details = result;

      changeDate();
    }, 0);
  });    
}
```

The concerts from that JSON are the next 50 gigs, so I have acquired links to the show pages to the last 50 concert entries to my database, which will match the JSON, like so:

```
    def index() 
{
    int eventCount = Event.count()
    int startingPoint = eventCount - 50

    def events = Event.createCriteria().list
    {
        order('id')
        firstResult(startingPoint)
        maxResults(50)
    }

    respond events
}
```

Trying to combine the JSON and the show links results in the two loops clashing and a 50 x 50 list results on the page - with each JSON entry have a link to each show or vice versa.

```
  <ul class="rel-results"> 
  <g:each in="${eventInstanceList}" status="i" var="eventInstance">
    <li ng-repeat="show in details">
        <!-- SHOW LINKS -->
        <g:link action="show" controller = "Event" id="${eventInstance.id}">Info</g:link>

        <div class = "event-date-time">{{ show.datetime }}</div>

        <div class = "event-item">  
          <div class = "nameAndTicket row" style="margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0">
            <span class="artist-name col-md-10">
              <a href="#/" id="{{ $index + 1 }}" ng-click="update(show)" class = "artist-item">
                  {{ show.artists[0].name }}
              </a>
            </span>

          </div>

          <div class="venueAndRSVP row" style="margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0">
            <span class="venue-name col-md-10">
              <a href="#/" id="{{ $index + 1 }}" ng-click="update(show)" class = "venue-item">           
                <div style = "text-transform: lowercase;display: inline-block;color: red;font-size: 80%;">at</div> {{ show.venue.name }}  {{ show.formatted_location }}
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    </g:each>
  </ul>
```

I have tried Angular unique filters and even hacky JS to remove duplicate links on a page, but I think these are the wrong ideas. I feel like I need to combine the g:each and the ng-repeat somehow - actually doing so does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT to add Event domain

```
class Event implements Rateable, Commentable  {


int bandsintown_id
String artist
String venue
String ticket_url
String ticketStatus
String eventTime
String livestream

static constraints = 
{
    bandsintown_id unique:true
    livestream nullable:true

}
```

Comment: Is eventInstanceId on the domain object the same id as on a json entry as returned by a call to http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search.json?&api_version=2.0&app_id=FYP&location=Dublin,Ireland ? If not is there a way to link the 2 data sources uniquely?

Comment: No, the two are essentially independent of eachother

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to display? e.g. for each database entry show a link to the full DB record & what exactly from json, how do the 2 link?

Comment: There is a JSON list of events on my page being displayed with angular. I want to display the link to the show page for the matching event which is in my database, in the matching <li> element. 

When I add in the g:each as above, it lists the 50 show links with each of my JSON listed events where every <li> element has a link to every show - so thats 50x50 = 2500 in the list. 

I recognise this might be hard to visualise! Thanks

Comment: I can see why it's doing that, for each database row you're iterating over you're iterating over every row in the json. What joins the 2 data sets? ID, name etc. Once we know this, you can just fetch the data from the DB list or json list for the matching row.

Comment: The 2 data sets are not connected. The JSON data and the DB data are the same data though, same variable names etc. I'm displaying the data via JSON and Angular as I have a few functions that I could not perform on the database data. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id from the json is stored in your Event domain so that is the best/most unique thing to use to link the 2 together, this works for me...

`EventController`

```
def showByBandId() {
    def event = Event.findByBandsintown_id( params.id )
    // add some error handling here in case event isn't found
    redirect ( action: 'show', id: event.id )
}
```

`homepage.gsp`

```
<div id="related_results">
    <g:render template="partials/shows" />
</div>
```

`shows.gsp`

```
...
<li ng-repeat="show in details">
<a ng-href="${createLink( controller: 'event', action: 'showByBandId' )}/{{show.id}}">Info</a>
....
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'Cannot get property 'ticket_url' on null object' error. I edited my original post to add my domain class.

Comment: I would rename your domain class property name to ticketUrl if possible, if the name in the DB is ticket_url you can add this to mapping e.g. `static mapping = { ticketUrl column: 'ticket_url' }`, Grails might not play nicely with the underscore in the property name

Comment: I have done that and the error still persists. The full error message reads 'Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error evaluating expression [Event.findByTicketUrl( show.ticket_url )?.id] on line [11]: Cannot get property 'ticket_url' on null object' -- this code is being injected by a <g:render>, could that be causing any issues?

Comment: I have also tried different combinations of ticketUrl / ticket_url and id / bandsintown_id

Comment: Yeah if you're loading as a template you would normally pass in data to model so I guess as your json isn't loaded till later Grails is going to complain, can you render the template after the json is available? The other option is of course to iterate over the database results and for each row fetch the json for the DB ticketUrl

Comment: I was able to take it out of the template and put it on my page. Doing that resulted in the same error; likewise when I put my JS fetching my JSON in the header instead of footer the error didn't change.

Comment: Can I see the whole of the gsp please, I've mimicked most of the setup here but am missing some of the angular scope stuff

Comment: I'm going to send a link to the gsp on GitHub if that's ok. The section in question, removed from the template, begins at line 108. The angular is in app.js if you need to have a look at that too --------https://github.com/tyronestock/fyp/blob/master/grails-app/views/main/homepage.gsp

Comment: Tried setting up your project at work but various URLs blocked by firewall, bandsintown etc,  will try at home later

Comment: Ok thank you, I experience that block too but use this chrome extension to work with it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en